# Does using a Hyper-V Ubuntu VM add more security when web browsing?

Tags: malware, web-browser, virtualization, web

I've always been concerned that my casual browsing of the web directly from Windows 10 could infect my PC.

How much added security (if any) could be obtained by using Hyper-V to run an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS virtual machine for web browsing? Is it any more secure?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Before asking this question you need to make a good look at your threat model. You need to make good thought of what dangers lurk from browsing the internet - malicious JS, exploit kits etc. Do you download and execute random files from the internet? It seems you've done apparently zero or near to zero research before asking your question. Also, as an alternative take a look at the Tails USB OS

Answer (score 2):

The idea you are describing is called "browser isolation" and it is very effective. There are even commercial services that offer it, hosted in the cloud.

If you host the VM on the same machine, you risk the possible, but unlikely, risk of an infection breaking out of the VM.

I used this method for a while and the hypervisor I used allowed me to display just the browser window in the host's desktop UI and not the full guest VM UI, making it convenient. That capability has been available for over a decade.

Bear in mind that modern browsers are already improving their browser sandbox capabilities, which improve the security of normal browsing. It's not as good as full browser isolation, but things are improving.

Comment: @how would you say that using an Ubuntu VM compares to Windows Sandbox?

Comment: A VM offers more separation than application sandboxing. But VMs perform worse.